# Why did Superman's body not decompose?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, justice-league-2017

In *Justice League*, a number of heroes band together and decide that they need Superman. Only problem is that he's dead (after the events of *Batman vs. Superman: Dawn of Justice*).

It's clearly been a while since his death, leaving time for Ma Kent to sell the house and Lois Lane to take a leave from work and then write fluff pieces. (Also, the entirety of *Suicide Squad* happened in the time after Superman died).

And yet Superman's body is perfectly preserved when they open his coffin. Why is it not the least bit decomposed? Does it have something to do with being a Kryptonian? Or is it just handwavey movie logic?

Comment: The tiniest, humblest creatures were defeated by this alien. Something doesn't sound right there

Comment: Unless I'm imagining things, it was explicitly stated in the movie that it was because Earth's microscopic life weren't able to affect his Kryptonian body.

Comment: I don't think they really mentioned why the body never began to decompose in the film, but I would argue that it has something to do with the dirt that began to rise off the coffin at the end of BvS. That is not normal and makes me say that superman was in a deep coma like the comics. That is why he did not decompose in my opinion. Solar radiation can penetrate the ground so I assume it was kind of an iron lung for him keeping him from truly dying. It was still a stupid way to "bring him back to life" either way...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that, in the DCEU, Kryptonians don't decompose all that fast. A key plot point of *Batman vs Superman* was that Zod's corpse still seems to be in good condition

[image]

Even if we presume that they froze the body, we only ever see Zod's corpse in what appears to be an unfrozen state (it seems highly unlikely it was frozen when Luthor cut off Zod's fingertips)